# JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I am trying to create a standalone client to consume some web services. I must add my username and password to the SOAP Header.  I tried adding the credentials as follows:

```
OTSWebSvcsService service = new OTSWebSvcsService();
OTSWebSvcs port = service.getOTSWebSvcs();

BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myusername");
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");

...
```

When I call a method on the service I get the following exception:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.SoapSecurityException: WSEC5048E: One of "SOAP Header" elements required.
```

What am I doing wrong?  How would I add these properties to the SOAP Header?

Edited:  I was using JAX-WS 2.1 included in JDK6.  I am now using JAX-WS 2.2.  I now get the following exception:

```
com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.SoapSecurityException: WSEC5509E: A security token whose type is [http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken] is required.
```

How do I go about creating this token?

Comment: Currently working with SOAP and having this same problem.
After having read all the answers in this question, I have the feeling I want to quit programming, which I love.
Honestly, I understand why nowadays everyone is using REST and why SOAP is such a terrible technology that should have never existed...

Comment: And special thanks to @hello_earth who pointed out in the exact places where others only give false clues.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not 100% sure as the question is missing some details but if you are using JAX-WS RI, then have a look at [Adding SOAP headers when sending requests](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/user-guide.html#adding-soap-headers-when-sending-requests):

> The portable way of doing this is that
>   you create a `SOAPHandler` and mess
>   with SAAJ, but the RI provides a
>   better way of doing this.
>
> When you create a proxy or dispatch
>   object, they implement
>   `BindingProvider` interface. When you
>   use the JAX-WS RI, you can downcast to
>   `WSBindingProvider` which defines a
>   few more methods provided only by the
>   JAX-WS RI.
>
> This interface lets you set an
>   arbitrary number of Header object,
>   each representing a SOAP header. You
>   can implement it on your own if you
>   want, but most likely you'd use one of
>   the factory methods defined on
>   `Headers` class to create one.
>
> ```
> import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider;
>
> HelloPort port = helloService.getHelloPort();  // or something like that...
> WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)port;
>
> bp.setOutboundHeader(
>   // simple string value as a header, like <simpleHeader>stringValue</simpleHeader>
>   Headers.create(new QName("simpleHeader"),"stringValue"),
>   // create a header from JAXB object
>   Headers.create(jaxbContext,myJaxbObject)
> );
> ```

Update your code accordingly and try again. And if you're not using JAX-WS RI, please update your question and provide more context information.

**Update:** It appears that the web service you want to call is secured with WS-Security/UsernameTokens. This is a bit different from your initial question. Anyway, to configure your client to send usernames and passwords, I suggest to check the great post [Implementing the WS-Security UsernameToken Profile for Metro-based web services](http://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/metro-usernametoken-profile) (jump to step 4). Using NetBeans for this step might ease things a lot.

Comment: I cannot get eclipse to import this `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider` class.

Comment: Will there be any portability issues if we use the classes from com.sum package?

Comment: Link to post about WS-Security is dead.

Comment: @pihentagy - I have `import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;`

Answer (score 45):

Data can be transferred in SOAP header (JaxWS) by using @WebParam(header = true):

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "SendRequest", action = "http://abcd.ru/")
@Oneway
public void sendRequest(
    @WebParam(name = "Message", targetNamespace = "http://abcd.ru/", partName = "Message")
    Data message,
    @WebParam(name = "ServiceHeader", targetNamespace = "http://abcd.ru/", header = true, partName = "ServiceHeader")
    Header serviceHeader);
```

If you want to generate a client with SOAP Headers, you need to use -XadditionalHeaders:

```
wsimport -keep -Xnocompile -XadditionalHeaders -Xdebug http://12.34.56.78:8080/TestHeaders/somewsdl?wsdl -d /home/evgeny/DEVELOPMENT/JAVA/gen
```

If don't need @Oneway web service, you can use Holder:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "SendRequest", action = "http://abcd.ru/")
public void sendRequest(
    @WebParam(name = "Message", targetNamespace = "http://abcd.ru/", partName = "Message")
    Data message,
    @WebParam(name = "ServiceHeader", targetNamespace = "http://abcd.ru/", header = true, partName = "ServiceHeader")
    Holder<Header> serviceHeader);
```

Comment: +1, the `-XadditionalHeaders` is an important attribute in this case.

Comment: header=true did the trick for me. I had make a copy the existing stub and set the header = true on the copy for the maven wsimport not to overwrite the generated stubs.

Comment: What is the equivalent in maven plugin for -additionalHeader ?

Comment: @AbdulRazakAK <args>-XadditionalHeaders</args>

Comment: For those who are using `wsdl2java` instead of `wsimport` the equivalent of `-XadditionalHeaders` is `-exsh true` (exsh stands for extended soap header binding and 'true' enables this) with an example command being:       `.\wsdl2java.bat -exsh true -autoNameResolution <wsdl-url>`

Comment: From which package you get Header class?

Answer (score 8):

I'm adding this answer because none of the others worked for me.

I had to add a **Header Handler** to the **Proxy**:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class SOAPHeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private final String authenticatedToken;

    public SOAPHeaderHandler(String authenticatedToken) {
        this.authenticatedToken = authenticatedToken;
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        Boolean outboundProperty =
                (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            try {
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPFactory factory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
                String prefix = "urn";
                String uri = "urn:xxxx";
                SOAPElement securityElem =
                        factory.createElement("Element", prefix, uri);
                SOAPElement tokenElem =
                        factory.createElement("Element2", prefix, uri);
                tokenElem.addTextNode(authenticatedToken);
                securityElem.addChildElement(tokenElem);
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
                header.addChildElement(securityElem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            // inbound
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return new TreeSet();
    }

    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        //
    }
}
```

In the proxy, I just add the Handler:

```
BindingProvider bp =(BindingProvider)basicHttpBindingAuthentication;
bp.getBinding().getHandlerChain().add(new SOAPHeaderHandler(authenticatedToken));
bp.getBinding().getHandlerChain().add(new SOAPLoggingHandler());
```

Comment: note that adding handlers this way won't work, because bp.getBinding().setHandlerChain(...) needs to be called - see rumberomelo's answer

Comment: also here's a better example specifically for UsernameToken headers scenario: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sc-and-ds/8.1.0?topic=client-soaphandler-example

Comment: Thanks @hello_earth, those 2 comments are exactly what it was need to bring light to this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Also, if you're using Maven to build your project, you'll need to add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>{currentversion}/version>
    </dependency>
```

This provides you with the class `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider`.

Link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt

Answer (score 5):

you can add the username and password to the SOAP Header

```
BindingProvider prov = (BindingProvider)port;
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                "your end point"));
Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myusername");
prov.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypassword");
prov.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

Comment: by far, the easiest and simple solution. PD: I didn't have any of the problems mentioned above using Maven, no need for `<args>-XadditionalHeaders</args>`, no extra dependencies

Comment: this wouldn't work if UsernameToken is required - this modifies the HTTP headers, not the SOAP message headers...

Comment: although Basic Authentication headers might also be required in UsernameToken scenario too....

Answer (score 3):

Use maven and the plugin [jaxws-maven-plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/). this will generate a web service client. Make sure you are setting the [xadditionalHeaders](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#xadditionalHeaders) to true. This will generate methods with header inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The best option (for my of course) is do it yourserfl. It means you can modify programattly all parts of the SOAP message

```
Binding binding = prov.getBinding();
   List<Handler> handlerChain = binding.getHandlerChain();
    handlerChain.add( new ModifyMessageHandler() );
    binding.setHandlerChain( handlerChain );
```

And the ModifyMessageHandler source could be

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage( SOAPMessageContext context )
{
    SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage(); 
    try
    {

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = msg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
        SOAPElement ele = header.addChildElement( new QName( "http://uri", "name_of_header" ) );
        ele.addTextNode( "value_of_header" );
        ele = header.addChildElement( new QName( "http://uri", "name_of_header" ) );
        ele.addTextNode( "value_of_header" );
        ele = header.addChildElement( new QName( "http://uri", "name_of_header" ) );
        ele.addTextNode( "value_of_header" );
```

...

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

In `jaxws-rt-2.2.10-ources.jar!\com\sun\xml\ws\transport\http\client\HttpTransportPipe.java`:

```
public Packet process(Packet request) {
        Map<String, List<String>> userHeaders = (Map<String, List<String>>) request.invocationProperties.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
        if (userHeaders != null) {
            reqHeaders.putAll(userHeaders);
```

So, `Map<String, List<String>>` from requestContext with key `MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS` will be copied to SOAP headers.
Sample of [Application Authentication with JAX-WS via headers](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/application-authentication-with-jax-ws/)

`BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY` and `BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY` keys are processed special way in `HttpTransportPipe.addBasicAuth()`, adding standard basic authorization `Authorization` header.

See also [Message Context in JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.java.net/articles/MessageContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with all the answers here, starting with [Pascal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323109/19820), which is getting harder with the Java compiler not binding against `rt.jar` by default any more (and using internal classes makes it specific to that runtime implementation).

[The answer from edubriguenti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36847739/19820) brought me close. The way the handler is hooked up in the final bit of code didn't work for me, though - it was never called.

I ended up using a variation of his handler class, but wired it into the `javax.xml.ws.Service` instance like this:

`Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
service.setHandlerResolver(
        portInfo -> Collections.singletonList(new SOAPHeaderHandler(handlerArgs))
);`

Answer (score -1):

Adding an object to header we use the examples used here,yet i will complete

```
  ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        CabeceraCR cabeceraCR =objectFactory.createCabeceraCR();
        cabeceraCR.setUsuario("xxxxx");
        cabeceraCR.setClave("xxxxx");
```

With object factory we create the object asked to pass on the header. The to add to the header

```
  WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)wsXXXXXXSoap;
        bp.setOutboundHeaders(
                // Sets a simple string value as a header
                Headers.create(jaxbContext,objectFactory.createCabeceraCR(cabeceraCR))
                );
```

We used the WSBindingProvider to add the header. The object will have some error if used directly so we use the method

```
objectFactory.createCabeceraCR(cabeceraCR)
```

This method will create a JAXBElement like this on the object Factory

```
  @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.creditreport.ec/", name = "CabeceraCR")
    public JAXBElement<CabeceraCR> createCabeceraCR(CabeceraCR value) {
        return new JAXBElement<CabeceraCR>(_CabeceraCR_QNAME, CabeceraCR.class, null, value);
    }
```

And the jaxbContext we obtained like this:

```
  jaxbContext = (JAXBRIContext) JAXBContext.newInstance(CabeceraCR.class.getPackage().getName());
```

This will add the object to the header.