# JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers in JBoss

Tags: java, soap, jboss, jax-ws, ws-addressing

I would like to set/get SOAP Headers (specifically `wsa:ReplyTo` and `wsa:MessageId`) in my Asynchronouse Webservice running on JBoss.

Since, this is a JBoss platform, I cannot use `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider` (as recommended in [JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322953/772000)).

One option would be to use `SOAPHandler`. Is there any other way similar to the `WSBindingProvider` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to use a specific handler for this.  Previous versions of JBOSS EAP did support the `javax.xml.ws.addressing` packages however it looks like these packages are not a part of EE6.

Define the handler e.g. `jaxws-handlers.xml` as:

```
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee javaee_web_services_1_3.xsd">

  <handler-chain>
    <protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP</protocol-bindings>
    <handler>
      <handler-name>Application Server Handler</handler-name>
      <handler-class>com.handler.ServerHandler</handler-class>
   </handler>
 </handler-chain>
```

Add `@HandlerChain` into the Service class definition:

```
@WebService (...)
@HandlerChain(file="jaxws-handlers.xml")
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
   public String sayHello(String name) {
      return "Hello " + name + "!";
   }
}
```

And implement the Handler itself as :

```
public class ServerHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
        final Boolean outbound = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        if ((outbound != null) && !outbound) {
            //...
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```