# JAX-WS SOAP Client with Password Digest

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, soap-client

I'm trying to create a client to a ws (using wsimport) that requires a UsernameToken header with digest.

The header must be like this:

```
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-32E6B34377D7E4A58614607283662392">
        <wsu:Created>xxxx</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>xxxxx</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32E6B34377D7E4A58614607283662221">
        <wsse:Username>xxxx</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">xxxxx</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xxxxxxx</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>xxxxxx</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

It seems to be a default soap header but I not found a easy way to generate it.

How can I add this header in my request?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-WS - Adding SOAP Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322953/jax-ws-adding-soap-headers)