# JAX-WS Request with Basic Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

i am trying to call a SOAP Webservice  using handlers with Basic Authorization but somehow API is responding with 401 unauthorized.

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        String authString = parameter.getUser() + ":" + parameter.getPassword();
        try {
             Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>)
                     context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);

             if (null == headers) {
                 headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
             }

             headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList(
                 "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(authString.getBytes()))));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log4j.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return outboundProperty;
}
```

When i use SOAP UI and manually add the Authorziation Header (value from code during debug) then i recieve response from the Endpoint but using code it fails as of now.

Any pointers would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: did you tried my updated answer bro?

Comment: @Spara using BASE64Encoder()  from sun misc did not help me.

Comment: Did you tried to return `true` instead of returning `outboundProperty`?

Comment: What happened bro? could you solve the problem? The bounty will disappear in 2 days

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071366/java-web-service-client-basic-authentication or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322953/jax-ws-adding-soap-headers/36847739#36847739 Im sure you can find the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change your code to like this:

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if(outboundProperty.booleanValue()){
        try{
            String authString = parameter.getUser() + ":" + parameter.getPassword();
            SOAPMessage soapMessage =context.getMessage();
            String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
            soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Authorization","Basic " + authorization);   
            soapMessage.saveChanges(); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            log4j.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Updated:

As explained [here](https://www.coderanch.com/wiki/659769/Web-Services)  you should use `Base64Coder` from `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()` for encoding `authString`

Also you should always return `true` from this method otherwise you will block processing of the handler request chain by returning `false`.

Comment: Can you highlight the actual change and provide an explanation?